# 'middleware fetch' It succeeds in the local development environment but fails in the staging environment

Tags: next.js, fetch, middleware

In the middleware I'm attemoting to call a next.js api page using the fetch API.This flow functions as expected in the local development environment, but encounters issues when deployed to the staging environment.

In the staging environment, the backend API does not receive the processing.
(The backend API by itself is functioning correctly, so I suspect that there might be an issue with the middleware,fetch part.)

I found some similar questions here and tried the suggested solutions, but it's not working for me.

middleware.ts

```
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_URL}/api/get-function`);

if (res.ok){

}
```

pages/api/get-function

```
  const response = await axios.get('/get-version');
  return res.status(response.status).json(JSON.parse(response.data));
```

Is it possible to consider other issues, such as network control problems, as the cause for this?

Thank you in advance.